# How to remove all permissions from role without recreating it in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a user role with lots of permissions (both grant and deny) on all sorts of different objects or schemas. The role also has many members. Now I have a new list of permissions that I want to apply for this role.

**How can I remove all existing permissions, so that the role is like a newly created, without actually dropping and recreating it?**

The point here is to allow "resetting" the permissions without the need of adding all role members again, or going through all existing permissions one-by-one.

Comment: Are you able to performe a restore of a backup or will there be data lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the role and creating it seems like the easiest thing, in my opinion. if you want to add all the old members to the new one, you could use a dynamic script.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10),
        @Role sysname = N'TestRole'; --This would be your role.


SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT @CRLF + N'ALTER ROLE ' + QUOTENAME(@Role) + N' ADD MEMBER ' + QUOTENAME(u.[name]) + N';'
                  FROM sys.database_principals r
                       JOIN sys.database_role_members drm ON r.principal_id = drm.role_principal_id
                       JOIN sys.database_principals u ON drm.member_principal_id = u.principal_id
                  WHERE r.[name] = @role
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'')

DROP ROLE TestRole; --This would be your role.

CREATE ROLE TestRole;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Note that you cannot drop a role that has members, so I edited your answer and added @SQLdrop to drop each member before dropping the role.